# How would you print the name of a file when it's read in as a pointer to an array?

Tags: c, pointers, formatting, printf

So, in this program I need to print the name of the file specified by the user when they run the program ./tstats input.txt. My problem is when I try to print out what the pointer is pointing too I get this: 84 18 407  ffbff2a4. Now I know exactly what the first 3 set of numbers are however that address I know has to with the pointer. I'm aware that my format for the print out needs to be in a string format however you can't print out a pointer in the format of a string. So here lies my question, how would you print out the name of the file by using what code I have now and my pointer to the input_from_args src?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


enum state
{
    START,
    WORD,
    DELIM,
};

FILE*
input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        return stdin;
    }
    else {
        return fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
}

void
wcount(FILE *src, FILE *dest)
{
    int ch, wc, lc, cc;
    enum state cstate;

    wc = lc = cc = 0;
    cstate = START;
    while ((ch = fgetc(src)) != EOF){
        cc++;
        switch (cstate) {
            case START:
                if (isspace(ch)) {
                    cstate = DELIM;
                    if (ch == '\n') {
                        lc++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cstate = WORD;
                    wc++;
                }
                break;
            case DELIM:
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    lc++;
                }
                else if (!isspace(ch)) {
                    cstate = WORD;
                    wc++;
                }
                break;
            case WORD:
                if (isspace(ch)) {
                    cstate = DELIM;
                    if (ch == '\n') {
                        lc++;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    fprintf(dest, "%4d\t%4d\t%4d\t%10p\n", wc, lc, cc, &src);
}
int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
    FILE *dest = stdout;

    if (src == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    wcount(src, dest);
    fclose(src);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

edit Question 2 code:

```css
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int i; 
 FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
 FILE *dest = stdout;
 
 
 for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
 {
  if ((src = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL)
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[i]); 
  }
  
  wcount(src, dest, get_filename_from_args(argc, argv[i]));
  fclose(src);
 }
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

Create a function that returns the filename to be printed by `wcount`:

```
char* get_filename_from_args(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static char stdin_name[] = "-";
    if (argc == 1) {
        return stdin_name;
    }
    else {
        return argv[1];
    }
}
```

Change the signature of `wcount`:

```
void wcount(FILE *src, FILE *dest, char* src_filename)
```

Change the call to `wcount`:

```
wcount(src, dest, get_filename_from_args(argc, argv));
```

Change the implementation of the line in `wcount` where you write out the details:

```
fprintf(dest, "%4d\t%4d\t%4d\t%s\n", wc, lc, cc, src_filename);
```

Comment: @R Sahu Ok, when I compile it with gcc -std=c89 I get the following Warning: In function 'get_filename_from_args': warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Thank you very much btw! Now I'm getting an warning in the main function: passing arg 2 of 'get_filename_from_args' from incompatible pointer type. Im assuming that has to do with the: wcount(src, dest, get_filename_from_args(argc, argv)); I think there should be a [] after argv but I get an error when I do that so... I'm not quite sure what the compiler is telling me.

Comment: You should change the type of `argv` in `main` to `char * argv[]`. Or change the signature of `get_filename_from_args` to also use `const char* argv[]`. But then, you'll need to change the return type to `const char*`.

Comment: do you mean in the calling of main or get_filename_from_args?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that question.

Comment: Well are you saying when I have int main(int argc, char* argv[]) should be changed to that, or wcount(src, dest, get_filename_from_args(argc, char* argv[])) to look like that? which call are you saying to change to char* argv[] ?

Comment: I am suggesting 1) Change `main` to `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. 2) Everything else remain as I suggested in my post.

Comment: Ok, I'm still receiving that warning.

Comment: Nvr, mind! I figured it out! It was in the input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[]) const char* argv[] should be char* argv[]

Comment: @R so I'm trying to increment my code so that the program will tally up all of the wc, lc, cc at the bottom and display the correct file name's next to each of their stats. Here's what my main fuction looks like now

Comment: In the updated `main`, you can just use `wcount(src, dest, argv[i]);` since `stdin` is not an option any longer.